# C# `BinaryReader.ReadBoolean` stuck

Tags: c#, tcp

**Client side:**

Something like my code:

```cs
var socket = Connect();
var reader = new BinaryReader(socket.GetStream());
var writer = new BinaryWriter(socket.GetStream());

// In other thread
writer.Write((byte) 5);
writer.Write("C:\\no-file.exe");
var exists = reader.ReadBoolean();
```

Stuck in `System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive`:

```cs
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.recv(this.m_Handle.DangerousGetHandle(), numPtr + offset, size, socketFlags);
```

I can see packet with my boolean value in WireShark, but `ReadBoolean` still executing and `socket.Available` equals zero.

**Server prototype:**

Minimal code that acts like a real server and causes the same problem.

```cs
var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 2386);
server.Start();

var socket = server.AcceptTcpClient();
socket.NoDelay = true;
Console.WriteLine("Connected: " + socket.Client.RemoteEndPoint);

var stream = socket.GetStream();
var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);

while (socket.Connected) {
    while (!stream.DataAvailable);

    if (stream.ReadByte() != 5) {
        break;
    }

    var path = reader.ReadString();
    Console.WriteLine("Requested file " + path);

    var exists = File.Exists(path);
    writer.Write(exists);

    writer.Flush();
    Console.WriteLine(exists ? "File exists" : "Not found");
}

Console.WriteLine("Disconnected: " + socket.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
```

Comment: What *exactly* did the other end send to you, and how did they form it? BinaryReader/BinaryWriter are very opinionated APIs, that are basically only compatible with their own twin (i.e. BinaryReader is compatible with BinaryWriter); they are *not* intended for general purpose stream handling of arbitrary protocols. Also, the code shown creates 2 readers - is that a typo?

Comment: Server using BinaryReader and BinaryWriter too, it waiting for string and sending boolean.

Comment: In which order? And did it flush? Is NoDelay enabled on the Socket? Etc; there are a *lot* of details that matter here

Comment: (quite honestly, there are virtually no scenarios when I recommend BinaryReader/BinaryWriter; I would *always* deal with the raw binary directly, although for convenience of buffer management and back-pressure, I would probably use the "pipelines" API over the socket)

Comment: I'll say it is a Flush problem... The `ReadBoolean` is as basic as it can be: `bool ReadBoolean() => InternalReadByte() != 0;`. The big problems with those classes were with `string` if I rememebr correctly

Comment: I've just tried your code and found it works fine. The only one thing i'd like to note is that service stuck on `while (!stream.DataAvailable);` when client exits. Even having TcpClient instance wrapped with `using`. But this is fine for TCP sockets - they are waiting some time for additional data (if any) from client. PS I've used two .Net 4.8 applications (client and server) to test

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found in my code that I have other thread that stole my boolean.

```cs
// TcpClient thread inside Connect method
while (client.Connected) {
    DispatchPacketType(stream.ReadByte());
}

// Thread that calls Connect
reader.ReadBoolean(); // stuck!
```

**EDIT:**

> So I made `WaitPacket` method to fix this problem. Not the best solution, but this works.

Making special waiting method was completely wrong, because it caused a lot of problems. The only one **normal decision is project refactoring**.

In same case you can try:

1. Refuse of while loop for reading packets (`DispatchPacketType`). Now client sends packet's type byte, its contents and reads server reply in same method (ex. `FetchSomeData`), because server (in my situation) responds sequentially.
2. Avoid interaction with the same `TCPClient` from multiple threads or use lockers as mentioned @500-Internal Server Error in his comment. I rewrote many lines of code and now it works more safier and performant.

Comment: This seems flaky to me: what if the `while` loop above runs right after your `WaitPacket(5)` call returns but before `reader.ReadBoolean()` gets a chance to execute?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I know that it is flaky, but I didn't see other way at the moment. It would be great if you can give me advice how properly get some data from network stream in other thread.

Comment: My clear advice is to not read from a single socket connection from multiple threads - it will cause nothing but headache. Instead, have a dedicated thread that reads chunks and puts those into a buffer, or multiple buffers that can be put on a queue. Multiple threads can then peek into the queue and/or dequeue from it after properly locking it (put locks around every access to the queue) so that threads don't mess up the data sequence for each other.